# Jinja2 block nesting issue

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) as a template language in my project. Here is simplified templates structure:

*base.html*:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

*content.html*:

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content">
        Content
        {% block sidebar %}
            <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        {% sidebar %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the result of *content.html* render:

```
<div class="content">
    Content
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
```

As you may see, `sidebar` is present twice at rendered `content.html`.

**Question:**

Is there a way to avoid appearance of the `sidebar` in `content`, leaving `{% block sidebar %}` inside `{% block content %}` ?

Comment: did you try this ? {% block content %}{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}

Comment: @Efazati In this case `sidebar` will be inside `content`, which is unacceptable. Thanks

Comment: i think you choose bad structure. maybe better create base like this <div class="content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
</div>
at all, see everything global. not just for case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your content.html template is invalid - you're clearly positioning sidebar related content inside the content block, so it will allways appear there. Also, your base.html seems invalid as well, it should look more like:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I made a typo at `base.html`, sorry. Speaking of `content.html` validity - I think it is invalid too. The best solution is to place `{% block sidebar %}` outside the `{% block content %}`. But according to complexity of project - I can not do that. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Why would you want to leave the block sidebar in content and not render it there at the same time? In other words: what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `Content.html` is generated automaticaly. I have ability to affect the content of `{% block content %}` of resulting `content.html` only.